# Regular expression [\n.]* does not seem to work to match anything

Tags: regex

I am trying to match any character or a new line and this arbitraryly often.
I tried `[\n.]*` but that did not seem to work. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: What environment? Is the regex multiline?

Comment: The dot is a real dot inside square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is match any character and are being thrown
off by the intent of the dot meta-character which means match  any
character except newlines.

The analogy of any character except a single character can be seen
using a character class.

For instance

And `[\a]` = `[A]`
Not `[\A]` = `[^A]`

Replacing Aa with Ss letters,
any character would be `[\s] or [\S]`.

Combining them into a class you'd get this

`[\S\s]`

the meaning of which is match any character and is not restricted
to the meaning of what a dot is as you go to and from a Unicode
environment.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated previously, the `dot` is an actual `dot` in the square brackets.  Try this instead

```
\n*|.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/DL6yuF/1

Comment: `(.|\n)*` would be closer to OP's intent

Comment: @EdwardMinnix The parentheses would create a group, which the OP does not have.

Answer (score 1):

The dot is a real dot inside a character class (square brackets), i.e. is not considered a [metacharacter.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash.